# Logical operators in if and scope of floating point

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, arithmetic-expressions

I have 2 float variables var_a and var_b

I want to execute a program if both of them are greater than zero.
I used the following snippet code

```
if(var_a > 0 and var_b > 0)
   execute()
```

It shows an error: invalid syntax.
I also wanted to check if float variables can deal with 4 digits after decimals. If not what should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `:` to the end of the first line!

Comment: and what about float for 4 digits

Comment: Of course float variables can handle four digits... and lots more.

Comment: It will deal! And you can round it to 4 by print('%10.4f' % your_variable).